# How to pass string without quotes in cassandra parameter of .execute method

Tags: python, database, cassandra, cql, cqlsh

My query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee.emp_details 
WHERE id = 7
```

This is my code

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

HOST = ['10.107.2.123']
PORT = '9042'
cluster = Cluster(HOST, PORT)
session = cluster.connect()

val = 'FROM'
rows = session.execute('''SELECT * %s employee.emp_details WHERE id = %s''', (val, 7))
```

This is the error that I am getting:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/sachhya/Documents/Example/ex.py", line 9, in 
>   rows = session.execute('''SELECT * %s employee.emp_details WHERE id = %s''', (val, 7))
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 2134, in execute
>   return self.execute_async(query, parameters, trace, custom_payload, timeout, execution_profile, paging_state).result()
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 4026, in result
>   raise self._final_exception
>   cassandra.protocol.SyntaxException:

I believe that my query string is something made like that after parameter bind. `SELECT * 'FROM' employee.emp_details WHERE id = 7`

Please help I need to use 'val' variable to bind in my query string.

Comment: why do you need to bind `'FROM'`?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you don't have to bind the FROM in your query. Use string formatting in this case:

```
rows = session.execute('''SELECT * {} employee.emp_details WHERE id = %s'''.format(val), (7,))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

HOST = ['10.107.2.123']
PORT = '9042'
cluster = Cluster(HOST, PORT)
session = cluster.connect()

val = 'FROM'
query = 'SELECT * {} employee.emp_details WHERE id = {}'.format(val, 7)

# or query = ('SELECT * %s employee.emp_details WHERE id = %s' % (a, 7))

rows = session.execute(query)
```

output from terminal:

```
>>> query = ('SELECT * %s employee.emp_details WHERE id = %s' % (a, 7))
>>> query
'SELECT * FROM employee.emp_details WHERE id = 7'

>>> query = 'SELECT * {} employee.emp_details WHERE id = {}'.format(a, 7)
>>> query
'SELECT * FROM employee.emp_details WHERE id = 7'
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you the power of prepared statements.

`from cassandra.cluster import Cluster`

`HOST = ['10.107.2.123']
 PORT = '9042'
 cluster = Cluster(HOST, PORT)
 session = cluster.connect()`

`val=7`

`query="SELECT * employee.emp_details WHERE id = ?"`
 `prepared_query=session.prepare(prepared_query)`

`results=session.execute(prepared_query,(val))`

`print results`

Use Prepared Statements to when you have to iterate through variables in query.

Visit: [Prepared Statements Docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/python/2.6/api/cassandra/query.html#cassandra.query.Statement)